# Adding axes labels to a Microcharts plot

Tags: xamarin, plot, charts

Im trying to create a nice plot with Xamarin and [Microcharts](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts). Unfortunately, Microcharts doesn't seem to be maintained any more and axes labels are [not supported](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/Microcharts/issues/97) directly.

I'm wondering whether there is a way to add axes labels manually. My code for plotting the signal looks as follows:

```
private void PlotSignals() {
    ChartView chartView = FindViewById<ChartView>(Resource.Id.chartView);
    var chart = new LineChart();
    chart.IsAnimated = false;
    chart.LineMode = LineMode.Straight;
    chart.PointMode = PointMode.None;
    var chartEntries = //my chart entries 
    chart.Entries = chartEntries;
    chartView.Chart = chart;
}
```

The corresponding .axml layout file looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_myActivity">

        <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <microcharts.droid.ChartView
            android:id="@+id/chartView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="160dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/StartButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Start"
        />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/StopButton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="Stop"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Based on my research, Microcharts cannot achieve it, so you can use OxyPlot to acheve that.http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/getting-started/hello-xamarin-android.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. However, I'm not making use of PCL and OxyPlot [doesn't support](https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot-xamarin/issues/82) .NET Standard 2.0. Are there any other free options available?

Comment: Could you try this https://www.shinobicharts.com/features/?

Comment: Thanks for the link but I'm looking for a free library. As far as I can tell, ShinobiCharts isn't free.

Comment: Well, I don't have a solution (yet).

Comment: Sorry, I read it wrong, normally,  we use these three kinds of plugins for charts, it seems that you have to wait update of Microcharts.

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find any solutions to this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I had to abandon my project. Did you try the github page and open an issue there?